# Where are docker events stored? Can they be redirected to syslog server?

Tags: docker, syslog

I have a server with docker running. I can use the command `docker events` to monitor events as they occur. But I can also use the command option `--since <timestamp>` to list previously occured events.

```
# docker events --since '2022-03-20'
2022-03-22T23:56:47.734684472Z network connect daee956f7a48538470209a02318f9312)
2022-03-22T23:56:47.975103504Z container start 8245dab2d81075a856594bb164be34ac)
2022-03-25T06:25:07.473690045Z container pause 8245dab2d81075a856594bb164be34ac)
2022-03-25T06:25:18.728654844Z container unpause 8245dab2d81075a856594bb164be34)
2022-03-25T06:25:26.919184476Z container exec_create: /bin/sh  8245dab2d81075a8)
2022-03-25T06:25:29.068042340Z container exec_start: /bin/sh  8245dab2d81075a85)
```

So the events must be stored somewhere. Where are they stored? I see that there is a `<contaniner-id>-json.log` but it is empty.

As a follow up question. Can I have these event logs redirected/copied to a syslog server instead?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, since I have the same need, that this was discussed by the Docker team and it was decided that this would result in a massive log file and be of little use to anyone. Then the ticket was [closed](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29548).

I cannot see any change in attitude towards this. There are plenty of ways to feed the stream of events into other logging/monitoring/dashboard tools so perhaps the Docker world has learned to live with it.

Personally I am going to write a `systemd` service to watch the stream, trim the data and write it to a log and let `logrotate` deal with it :)